# Why do I get error while installing gensim package

Tags: python, gensim

```
Building wheels for collected packages: gensim
  Building wheel for gensim (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for gensim (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [714 lines of output]

building 'gensim.models.word2vec_inner' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for gensim
Failed to build gensim
ERROR: Could not build wheels for gensim, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I tried a couple of things but nothing seems to work, please let me know how we can resolve this issue?

Comment: What is your python version?

Answer (score -2):

Building the supporting native libraries on Windows machines can be somewhat finicky requiring extra tools, & different from the better-supported Unix-ish (Linux/MacOS) environments.

So, if your Windows install is trying that rather than using some precompiled wheels, the situation is suboptimal and likely to fail without hand-holding.

You may be using Python 3.12, for which (as of this answer in early February 2024) Gensim hasn't yet ensured prebuilt wheels for all environments – see open project issues [#3510](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/3510) & [#3511](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/issues/3511), which should eventually be fixed so that standard `pip` installs just work.

Until then, your best workaround may be to use a slightly-older Python like 3.11. A tool like `conda` can make it easy to manage virtual environments that use specific Python versions, such as those older or newer than your system's standard Python. (I prefer the `miniconda` install for keeping things simple and explicit.)